# Generation of a self-signed certificate: unexpected token 'Signature' in expression or statement

Tags: certificate, signature, self-signed

In PowerShell I'm trying to generate a self-signed certificate. Here's the code with the error message

```
    $notBefore = Get-Date -Date "2023-07-20 00:00:00Z"
    $notAfter = Get-Date -Date "2032-12-20 00:00:00Z"
    $certificateName = "XYZ"
    $subject = "CN=" + $certificateName
    New-SelfSignedCertificate -Type Custom -NotBefore $notBefore -NotAfter $notAfter -DnsName
    $certificateName -KeySpec Signature -Subject $subject -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -
    HashAlgorithm sha256 -KeyLength 2048 -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My" -TextExtension    @("2.5.29.37={text}1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2")`

    At line:6 char:18
    + $certificateName -KeySpec Signature -Subject $subject -KeyExportPolic ...
    +                  ~~~~~~~~
    Unexpected token '-KeySpec' in expression or statement.
    At line:6 char:27
    + $certificateName -KeySpec Signature -Subject $subject -KeyExportPolic ...
    +                           ~~~~~~~~~
    Unexpected token 'Signature' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

Googling the error message, incl checking StackOverflow, hasn't helped so I'm trying here. Many thanks!